# Nginx active passive load balancing, backup machine should continue to serve even when the primary is back

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

```
upstream backend {
server 192.168.0.135:8085   fail_timeout=1s max_fails=1 weight=5;
server 192.168.0.157:8085   backup fail_timeout=1s max_fails=1 weight=5;
}
server {
listen 7777;
server_name 192.168.0.15;
}
```

I am trying to create a active-passive load balancing with the nginx running on 192.168.0.15 and two web servers running at 0.135 and 0.157. When the primary is down all the requests are being served by the backup 0.157 and when the primary is back then all the requests are being served by the primary.

But I want the backup to continue to serve even when the primary is up and how can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do You want to get active .157 after .135 fail and do not return back after .135 will restore? Or what.

Comment: When 135 (primary) and 157(backup) are both running all the requests are served by 135. When 135 is down 157 serves all the requests and after a while when 135 recovers and comes up then nginix transfers all the requests to 135 but i want 157 to continue to be active and serve requests. And when 157 is down then the requests should go to 135.

Comment: Can you explain reason why you want it? It will help me to find more solutions.

Comment: There are other services running apart from the web server and those services take time to switch and loose some data. So the switch back to primary from backup is not preferred. Also my primary and backup machines are identical in all aspects so why switch when it is not required?

Comment: There is no builtin solution for leave backup server active. Nginx is load balancer, and you question about HA. You can write additional scripts for edit config file and grace reload nginx. In case of Nginx PLUS upstream_conf module available for on-fly changes. But it's look like you need to change backend failover logic. May be using floating IP's (if both backends in same datacenter)